# regular locus of an affine domain

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an affine domain over a field $k$ (need not be algebraically closed). Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$, such that $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a regular local ring. Does there always exist a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$, such that $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$, and $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is also a regular local ring?

Comment: Don't understand why people are in such a hurry to reply without even understanding the question!

Comment: How about taking the localization of $k[X,Y]/(Y²-X²(X+1))$ at the nodal singularity? The result is local ring of dimension 1 which is not regular. However, the field of fractions is a regular local ring. This should be a negative answer to the question.

Comment: I need some maximal ideal (not all!) containing the prime ideal. Sorry to say, but you've also failed to understand the question!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed the affine domain condition. Maybe (assuming characteristic 0) you can use openness of the smooth locus to get a positive answer. I still think that my example gives a negative answer if you omit the condition that $A$ is an affine domain - $\mathfrak{p}=(0)$ and there is only one maximal ideal.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt No need to assume characteristic 0. What you say works for any affine algebra over any field.

Comment: Can you please tell me a reference for the fact that the regular locus of any affine algebra over a field is open?

Comment: The regular locus is open more generally for finite type algebras over a complete local ring (search for "excellent rings" if you want to explore this condition in more generality, for instance in EGA IV, 6 and 7).

Comment: I voted to close this because this is about a basic topic in commutative algebra.